# How to fit three divs into window's height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a chat project with Bootstrap and I have issues positioning my divs. Here's my pattern:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- #header -->
        <h1>Header stuff</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!-- #main -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <ul>Chat messages</ul> <!-- #chatbox -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>Users list</ul> <!-- #users -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!-- #input -->
        <form>Input zone</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what I want is to fit these 3 row sections into the browser's height, so that the input zone is always at the bottom of the screen and the page is not scrollable, but I want both the `#chatbox` and the `#users` to be scrollable so that they fit in the `#main`.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body > .container {
    height: 100%; /* Fit the container into the window */
}

.row#main > div {
    max-height: 100%; /* This doesn't */
    overflow: auto;   /*    work :(   */
}

.row#input { /* Stick the input zone at the bottom */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

But when I extend the `#chatbox` or the `#users`, I don't get a good result :(

Anyone's got an idea? I'd like a full-CSS solution if possible :3

Thanks ^^

Comment: "I don't get a good result" Please be more specific and objective about what behavior you are getting and how it differs from your desired behavior. We're not mind-readers here.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: Your selectors are unnecessarily specific and probably syntactically invalid. If you're using IDs, you don't have to conjugate with a class.

Comment: Your problem is best solved with flexbox. What browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a little demo for you to resolve this issue. Its pure CSS and suitable for any responsive layout.

You need to use the absolute position cleverly.

**demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/h87p14tx/2/

HTML

```
<div class="row header"> <!-- #header -->
    <h1>Header stuff</h1>
</div>
<div class="row main"> <!-- #main -->
    <div class="col-sm-9 chatbox"> <!-- #chatbox -->
        <ul>Chat messages</ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 users">  <!-- #users -->
        <ul>Users list</ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row input"> <!-- #input -->
    <form>Input zone</form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header, .input {
    width: 100%; position: absolute;
    background: red;
}

.header {
    top: 0;
    height: 70px;
}

.input {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.main {
    width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 70px; bottom: 50px;
    background: green;
    overflow: auto;
}

.chatbox, .users{
    height: 100%;
}

.main .chatbox{
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

.main .users{
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Well that's clever ! Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are essentially creating a header/body/footer layout, this should do the job:

```css
html, 
body {
  min-height: 100%; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 100px 0;
  top:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  left:0; 
  right:0;
  background-color: red;
}

#header {
  margin-top:-100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background-color: blue;
}

#body {
  min-height: 100%
}

#footer {
  height: 100px; 
  margin-bottom: -100px; 
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" class="container">
    <div id="header" class="row"> <!-- #header -->
        <h1>Header stuff</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="row"> <!-- #main -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <ul>Chat messages</ul> <!-- #chatbox -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>Users list</ul> <!-- #users -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="row"> <!-- #input -->
        <form>Input zone</form>
    </div>
</div>
```